# How to set editable mode true for a child grid view

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

There is a button and by clicking on it I need to set the editable mode true for a child grid view and I'm using *telerik grid view*

I realized I can write this code but it's not working

```
radGridView1.MasterTemplate.Templates[0].AllowEditRow = true;
```

Here is more info on my code

```
   public Inventory_List()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        radGridView1.MasterTemplate.Templates[0].ReadOnly = true;
    }

    private void Inventory_List_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'sales_and_Inventory_SystemDataSet.Inventory' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        inventoryTableAdapter.Fill(sales_and_Inventory_SystemDataSet.Inventory);
        radGridView1.Columns[1].MinWidth = 138;
        radGridView1.Columns[0].MinWidth = 95;
    }
```

And here's the bottumn I told you that has to set editable mode true

```
    private void btnDt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        radGridView1.MasterTemplate.Templates[0].AllowEditRow = true;
              //radGridView1.BeginEdit();
              btnSv.Focus();
    }
```

it's not working I have no idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the readOnly status to false.

```
radGridView1.MasterTemplate.Templates[0].ReadOnly = false;
radGridView1.MasterTemplate.Templates[0].AllowEditRow = true;
```